# XBOX 360 Disc error

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

My Xbox 360 is having issues reading some discs. I recently bought Minecraft (pre-owned), and it is really good condition (no scratches or marks). I also wiped my disc lots of times using micro-fiber wipes, but the Xbox still won't read the disc.

I tried old games and they all worked on the console, but new games always say "unrecognized disc". It is so annoying.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! At this point, it's a bit hard to identify what your issue is. Can you please clarify: 1. Is your Minecraft Disc *new* or *pre-owned/secondhand*? 2. Is Minecraft not working on your Xbox 360?

Comment: it's pre-owned. but it has zero scratches and the condition is the best

Comment: Do you know anyone else with a 360 who could test the disc?